# Visual Studio 2008: how to save project properties as a property sheet to be used in other projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, propertysheet, project-properties

I know how to add a property sheet to a VS2008 project. But I don't know how to save the properties of a VS2008 project as a property sheet to be used later in future projects. Does anybody know how? Do I have to manually create a property sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a property sheet with the propery manager. Then you can edit the property sheet in the same way as you would do with your projects properties. There is no way other the cut&paste to move property items with the Visual Studio 2008.

I prefer to close project and property sheet and use a graphical diff tool like Beyond Compare. This allows a quick move and/or copy of project properties to a property sheeet file. But beware that you must have understood the structure of the project file to do this.